# Canont Extend Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel 4 project when I log in I get the same error, my code looks fine and no errors on composer update / install.

**Error**

```
Class User cannot extend from trait Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser
```

**Code**

```
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

 class User extends ConfideUser {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    use HasRole;

    public $_origPass;

    public $autoHashPasswordAttributes = true;
    ......
```

Any ideas, I use this class https://github.com/Zizaco/confide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser is a trait not a class.

Change the start of your class with the following;

```
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUserInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Eloquent implements ConfideUserInterface {

    use ConfideUser;
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
```

Comment: I'll mark you correct would like to fix this though

Comment: @Brent ill edit the answer. Added the extends \Eloquent